# Spring: How to access a txt file located outside the jar?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Currently, I am passing the environment specfic configs in a properties file outside the jar using `-Dspring.config.location=/apps/conf/application-dev.properties`. I also have properties file included in the jar named `application.properties` which has configs that don't change often. There's one config called `nameFile`:

```
nameFile=classpath:config/nameList.txt
```

And the actual `nameList.txt` is included in the jar under `spring-app/src/main/resources/config/nameList.txt` but I want to move the nameList.txt outside the jar.

What I've tried:

1. Changing it to `nameFile =${auth.nameList}` and added this to `/apps/conf/application-dev.properties` like:

```
auth.nameList=classpath:/apps/conf/nameList.txt
```

And I moved the nameList.txt file from the jar to `/apps/conf/` location but the Spring application fails because it cannot find the txt file. How do I fix this? I want to move the nameList.txt to outside the jar.

2. Removed classpath:

```
auth.nameList=/apps/conf/nameList.txt
```

No luck!

Comment: `classpath` indicates that the file is within the jar. That's likely the issue.

Comment: @JettoMartínez I changed it to `auth.nameList=/apps/conf/nameList.txt` and still the same issue

Comment: I'm guessing there is an `/apps` folder in the root directory, yes? Otherwise, you'll need the whole path like `/home/user/apps/conf/nameList.txt`

Comment: Yes. `/apps` folder is in the root directory

Comment: My bad, I forgot `file:`. Please try with `file:/apps/conf/nameList.txt`

Comment: That worked! Thank you.

Comment: Great. I'll post it as an answer so it helps others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide a path, `classpath` will "tell" the JVM that the location is within the jar/war file. If you have the resource you need in an external location, you will need `file` instead.

```
auth.nameList=file:/apps/conf/nameList.txt
```